# How to get Jenkins Job execution start time

Tags: jenkins

I have configured jenkins email notification and I'm getting it properly.

But, How can I get at what time the Job execution has been started ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking for this issue to get fixed actually https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26520

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins provides a plugin called [Timestamper](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper) that can be used to provide time stamps in your console output.  The output will look like this...

> 21:51:15  Started by user anonymous
>
> 21:51:15  Building on master
>
> 21:51:17  Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Thanks!! I'm specifically looking for Time of Execution start in Email notification.